# Making a hexagonal plot with elements being weighted in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hexagonal-tiles

Using matplotib in python it is possible to make a simple histogram by providing the list of items to be plotted together with a list of weights, such that the contribution of each item to the bin to which it belongs is adjusted according to its weight, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

plt.hist(items, weights = weightsOfItems)
```

I am trying to plot a hexagonal bin histogram of two values against each other, which can be done using

```
plt.hexbin(xValues, yValues)
```

As before, I would like the contributions of each pair to the bin to which it belongs to be adjusted according to a list of weights. From the [`hexbin` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) it seems like I should be able to do this by giving an input for the parameter C, i.e.

```
plt.hexbin(xValues, yValues, C = weightsOfValues)
```

Doing this, however, yields completely incorrect plots. For the time being I have resorted to first sampling my xValues and yValues according to the weights to give xSamples and ySamples. This process, however, is very time consuming and also means that I do not use all of the data available since I get rid of xValues and yValues not included in the samples.

So, does anyone know of a way to produce a hexagonal bin histogram where the contribution of values to their respective bins is adjusted for according to given weights?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html):

> If `C` is specified, it specifies values at the coordinate (`x[i]`,`y[i]`). These values are accumulated for each hexagonal bin and then reduced according to `reduce_C_function`, which defaults to numpy’s mean function (`np.mean`). (If `C` is specified, it must also be a 1-D sequence of the same length as `x` and `y`.)

This means that for each bin, the corresponding `C` values are stored and then the `reduce_C_function` is applied to them. As the default function is `np.mean`, the result is not what you want to obtain but the mean instead of the sum. To actually get the sum of all the weights, this should be changed to `np.sum` in order to sum the values of `C` for each `(x,y)` in the bin instead of averaging them.

This example shows the difference with simple data:

```
N = 10**5
x = np.random.normal(size=N)
y = np.random.normal(size=N)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4)); plt.subplot(131)
plt.hexbin(x,y); plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(132)
plt.hexbin(x,y,C=np.ones(N)); plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(133)
plt.hexbin(x,y,C=np.ones(N),reduce_C_function=np.sum)
plt.colorbar(); plt.tight_layout()
```

Now the weights are set to 1 for all the values (generated from a Gaussian distribution), so that a proper algorithm for weighted histograms should return the same as the unweighted histogram. The output are the following plots:

[image: Different reduce_C_function]

The left panel is an unweighted plot, showing the 2D Gaussian, the middle panel is the default behaviour of `C`, averaging all `C` values per bin, thus, having a count of 1 in all the bins, and the right panel is the behaviour with `np.sum`, where the 2D Gaussian is retrieved.